# Can't change session duration

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, session

I have a login system on GoDaddy’s Economy hosting which I get logged out after 30 minutes of inactive, I tried change the session duration to a day with this:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400      // in .htaccess,
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400              // in php.ini
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);   // and
session_set_cookie_params(86400);           // at the beginning of each page
```

but it’s still not working

Comment: Are you sure the session isn't being expired by the PHP application? This is much more likely than it being an issue witht the PHP config. Check the configuration / code of your app to see if it allows the session length to be adjusted.

Comment: where do I check that

Comment: It depends on how your app is made. If it's built on an open-source platform (e.g. WordPress) then you should be able to find the answer in the documentation. If it's a custom system, you will either need to speak to the person who programmed it or look through the code yourself.

Comment: what might cause this in the code